# Warnings when compiling Boost libraries in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, boost, c++builder

I am getting warnings when I am trying to include `<boost/thread.hpp>` in C++ Builder. For every unit I am including it, C++ Builder shows up these 2 lines:

```
thread_heap_alloc.hpp(59): W8128 Can't import a function being defined
thread_heap_alloc.hpp(69): W8128 Can't import a function being defined
```

Already tried some things, nothing worked though.

It compiles correctly, however, it's getting on my nerves. Why is this message being shown?

The lines are:

```
#include <boost/config/abi_prefix.hpp>

namespace boost
{
    namespace detail
    {
        inline BOOST_THREAD_DECL void* allocate_raw_heap_memory(unsigned size)
        { 
            void* const eap_memory=detail::win32::HeapAlloc(detail::win32::GetProcessHeap(),0,size);
            if(!heap_memory)
            {
                throw std::bad_alloc();
            }
        return heap_memory;
    }

    inline BOOST_THREAD_DECL void free_raw_heap_memory(void* heap_memory)
    {
        BOOST_VERIFY(detail::win32::HeapFree(detail::win32::GetProcessHeap(),0,heap_memory)!=0);
    }
```

where 59 is the `{` below the `BOOST_THREAD_DECL`, as is 69. Looks like `BOOST_THREAD_DECL` is not defined properly or mis-defined, trying to follow through the Boost code is not that easy.

This is Boost 1.39.

Comment: What version of Boost do you use? What do you see at the above lines in `thread_heap_alloc.hpp`?

Comment: I'm using XE4. This is the file where the error occures : http://www.xup.in/dl,47109567/thread_heap_alloc.txt/

Comment: What if you use Boost 1.53? 1.39 was released 4 years and 7 days ago...

Comment: Thanks for the hint, gotta try it. Though Embarcadero delivers 1.39 pre-installed..

Comment: @KennyTM 1.53 is not an option with the 32 bit compiler from Embarcadero, only the 64 bit.  We are stuck at 1.39

Comment: Edit : Got the same problems using XE3, XE2 and XE1 both on my PC and my Laptop. Even though Emba installed 1.5 as well, it is only usable when using X64 : "Boost Version 1.50.0 is used only for the 64-bit Windows target platform."

Comment: Seems like I am not getting these messages when using X64 + Boost 1.5x. However, unfortunatly, this is no option for me..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add #define BOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB before including the thread.hpp.

This is what I tested:

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB
extern "C"
{
   namespace boost
   {
      void tss_cleanup_implemented( void )
      {
         /*
         This function's sole purpose is to cause a link error in cases where
         automatic tss cleanup is not implemented by Boost.Threads as a
         reminder that user code is responsible for calling the necessary
         functions at the appropriate times (and for implementing an a
         tss_cleanup_implemented() function to eliminate the linker's
         missing symbol error).

         If Boost.Threads later implements automatic tss cleanup in cases
         where it currently doesn't (which is the plan), the duplicate
         symbol error will warn the user that their custom solution is no
         longer needed and can be removed.*/
      }
   }
}
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
```

Then set 'Link with Dynamic RTL' and 'Link with Runtime Packages'.

This does a clean build and starts a thread properly.

Comment: I've found some interesting background to this problem, which suggest to not implement tss_cleanup_implemented carelessly: https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=778808#778808

Comment: @Gregor Brandt The link to the blog post seems broken, can you fix it?

Comment: @RadiumZheng sorry, blog is down right now.  I intend to get it back up before Christmas.  I will modify my answer.

Comment: @Gregor Brandt Any chance to get that blog up and running??

Comment: blog is down for foreseeable future, sorry.